# Variable height horizontal list of images height 100% width auto

Tags: html, css

I have a project where there is a vertical scrolling list of images that responds to view-port size. This is pretty standard and works as expected. When the view-port gets to a large enough size, I want the list to become horizontal where each list item is a height relative to the view-port - *SO, the opposite*

I thought that setting the images to `height: 100%;` and `width: auto;` would do the trick, but I think it's more complex than that.

Do you know the secret combo of rules that can accomplish this?

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/qZvmzM?editors=1100)

(resize your browser VERTICALLY to see how it breaks)

EDIT: this has less to do with scrolling that it does with width vs height issues in the browser calculations: [here is a more targeted CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/yOrBRJ) (which I would still like to understand)
[Here is a JS approach](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/NNmWRr) I may go with in the meantime:

### HTML

```
<ul class='image-list horizontal'>
    <li>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/1200x900' alt='x'>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS (stylus)

```
html, body
    height: 100%

html
    box-sizing: border-box

* //
    box-sizing: border-box

.image-list //
    list-style: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    border: 4px solid blue
    * //
        padding: .3rem
    li //
        border: 4px solid gray
    img //
        display: block
        border: 3px solid #f06
    
.horizontal
    height: 80% // variable
    max-width: 100%
    white-space: nowrap
    overflow-x: scroll
    li //
        height: 100%
        display: inline-block
    img //
        width: auto
        height: 100%

.vertical
    overflow: scroll
    li //
        width: 100%
    img //
        width: 100%
        height: auto

        

// just for position
.horizontal
    width: 80%
    float: right
    max-width: 100%
.vertical
    width: 20%
    height: 100%
```

Comment: I've looked at your demo on Codepen, but I'm still not clear on how it's actually supposed to look. Can you describe it to me a different way? If I'm understanding, though, what if you add `height: 100%;` to `<ul class="image-list horizontal">`?

Comment: When you land on the CodePen, that is basically how it is supposed to look. When you drag your screen - you'll see that the images break out of their corresponding `li`s. If I add `height: 100%;` to the `ul`, I'll have to add that to all of it's parents up to the `html` or it wont know what to be 100% of - and I'm not sure that solves the real problem. Let me know if this helps. Thanks @AndyHoffman

Comment: To further clarify, Is is supposed to look how it currently does - however when the browser height changes(drag it), the list height changes(as it should) - but the images break the structure in a way that I didn't expect.

Comment: Setting `.horizontal img` to `max-width: 100%;` keeps the images from breaking out of their `<li>` parents.

Comment: @AndyHoffman - if you do that, the image distorts and changes it's ratio. I can't have the images doing that. / it does however keep it inside the box. : )